# Uploaded timestamp with Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I have a model containing several PDFs that are stored on S3 using Carrierwave, and would like to display the *uploaded_at* timestamp of these files in a view.

I don't see any way to accomplish this built into Carrierwave.  Right now I plan to add an *uploaded_timestamp* field to the model, but am looking for a more elegant way to accomplish this.

Suggestions welcome.

Comment: creating a `uploaded_at` sounds good actually.. my suggestion is that you go that way..

Comment: Yeah... It would work.  I find it hard to believe that this isn't a common request with file uploads though. I thought there might be an add-on to build it into carrierwave.

Comment: is really simple to solve actually, doesn't worth to install a gem just to do that (just my opinion off course, also that installing a lot of gems makes your app slower).

Comment: the other thing you could do is to move your uploader to its own class, and make a `has_many, has_one` association, with this you could use the updated_at/created_at timestamp of that class to fit your needs